# Android/iphone InApp purchase data management to google play/ app store by using own website

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, google-play

My question will be different from development but I am stuck at this point and any help is appreciated.

I am developing an In app Purchase app for Android and iPhone using the standard API. My client doesn't want to use Google play administration interface to manage my in app purchase item. He wants his own implementation (his own administrator site) to upload new files to Google play or app store. So is there any API available to communicate app store and Google play to manage in app purchase data from their own web site?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are currently no APIs to support this.

The closest thing would be the [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/index), but that currently only supports checking the status of and cancelling a user's subscription purchases.

Comment: IS there any other way to implement InApp Purchase on 3rd party cloud service?.. or is it possible to create my own InApp server and manage it by own? if you have any reference or guideline than please share here .

Comment: Not if you are distributing the app on Google Play.
Check out the in-app purchases section of the [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages).